# Javascript Regex to validate URL and Empty at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I tried to write a regular expression to work with the position-absolute jQuery validation plugin to give error if the string is left empty OR its a invalid URL. It works well for the URl but doesn't give error if a empty string is there . Here's the regex

```
 "regex": /^\S$|^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/,
```

Can somebody tell what's wrong in the regex?

EDIT:

I'm using this plugin for jQuery validation

Demo: Go to this URL and in the URL validtion section, remove HTTP and see the error messages

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

When I add required and URL validators together, it shoots 2 errors. But with only URL
validator, it doesn't say that its a Invalid URL. I just need 1 error for both Empty and 
Invalid URL.

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Thanks

Comment: When tested against the empty string, the regex returns false.

Comment: But sadly it doesn't work with the validation plugin :( and the validation doesn't show popup error.

Comment: Perhaps you need to make the field required. I assume the plugin does not use the regex on empty fields.

Comment: Actually that's the main problem, we want the required validation in the regex only, so even if the field is left blank, it gives an error - Invalid URL, and not 2 errors like Field required and Invalid URL

Comment: You can set the error message to be the same one (Invalid URL), for both missing values and invalid values.

Comment: Tried that, it pops up 2 different error messages of * Invalid URL :(

Comment: No, use the generic `data-errormessage` instead of setting an `alertText` for both

Comment: Working now with your suggestion. Thanks :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the same generic error message for all errors using `data-errormessage`, so regardless of whether the field is empty or has an invalid value you will get the same message.

Comment: The problem is, when I use it for 2 different error messages, it pops up both the error messages. You can see it here: http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html, just make the URL field empty and see the errors.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to tell you. Don't use "Invalid URL" twice in separate places. Only use it once for the data-errormessage attribute.

Comment: Working now, Sorry was not able to understand that straight away, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [jQuery URL validation metohod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/url) ?

Comment: I'm using a different plugin for URL Validation, and for all other errors on the site this plugin works. It only messes up for the URL field. Can't change the validation method as we will have to change a lot of things. Better to get this one thing fixed :) - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small example how you could validate a email realy quick and easy. Without the hassle of using a plugin. If you use it just once you could just use

```
var emailaddressVal = 'nobody@example.cpom';

var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if(emailReg.test(emailaddressVal) && emailaddressVal.length > 0)
{
    alert('Your email is valid.');
}
else
{
    alert('The email is invalid')
}
```

However putting it in a function so you could use it multiple times. than put it in a function for example:

```
// Email check function 
function checkEmail(email)
{
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if(emailReg.test(email) && email.length > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Ussage 
if(checkEmail('nobody@example.com'))
{
    alert('SUCCESS!!');
}
else
{
    alert('FAILED!!');
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the regex when used in that particular prlugin. The problem is, when I use it for 2 different error messages, it pops up both the error messages. You can see it here: position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/…, just make the URL field empty and see the errors.